# Error While Reading a version from Databricks Delta Sharing CDF (Change Data Feed) API

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, delta-sharing

I am attempting to read a particular version from the Databricks Delta Sharing CDF (Change Data Feed) API.

Though version contains only one data file, an error occurs due to a timeout with following message:

```
"errorCode": "RESOURCE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED",
"message": "A timeout occurred when processing the table after 3 updates across 1 iterations. If it continues to happen, please contact your data provider and request them to optimize their table so that it has fewer files."
```

API(You will not be able to use it, as token is required):

```
https://eastus2-c2.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/delta-sharing/metastores/949ae2f5-8c64-4c5c-83a6-a4532259a54f/shares/demo/schemas/appevents/tables/auditlogs/changes?startingVersion=40000&endingVersion=40000
```

The 40000th version has:

- data size ~ 10KB
- And only 1 file.

Any help is appreciated!!